# FilterOn and DynamicCriteria allowed values for MS Graph Excel Filter Criteria

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, filtering

I am looking for the allowed values for the `filterOn` and `dynamicCriteria` properties shown in the filter criteria described at [Filter: apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/filter-apply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). The sample values provided in the documentation are so generic that I can't understand what are valid values.

[image: Example Call]

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/tables/{id|name}/columns/{id|name}/filter/apply
Content-type: application/json

{
  "criteria": {
    "criterion1": "criterion1-value",
    "criterion2": "criterion2-value",
    "color": "color-value",
    "operator": {
    },
    "icon": {
      "set": "set-value",
      "index": 99
    },
    "dynamicCriteria": "dynamicCriteria-value",
    "values": {
    },
    "filterOn": "filterOn-value"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtering criteria applied to a column are not documented but it's very similar to Excel Javascript API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.filtercriteria?view=excel-js-preview

1. `filterOn` property

Determines whether the values should stay visible.

Possible values are: `BottomItems`, `BottomPercent`, `CellColor`, `Dynamic`, `FontColor`, `Values`, `TopItems`, `TopPercent`, `Icon`, `Custom`

Example of the request body for `Values`. Lets say you have the following table and you want to select values 1,3 and 5 from Column1

[image]

```
POST /v1.0/me/drive/items/{item_id}/workbook/tables/{table_name}/columns/1/filter

{
  "criteria": {
    "color": null,
    "criterion1": null,
    "criterion2": null,
    "filterOn": "Values",
    "dynamicCriteria": "Unknown",
    "icon": null,
    "operator": "And",
    "values": [
        "1",
        "3",
        "5"
    ]
  }
}
```

Display values greater than 2

```
{
    "criteria": {
        "color": null,
        "criterion1": ">2",
        "criterion2": null,
        "filterOn": "Custom",
        "dynamicCriteria": "Unknown",
        "icon": null,
        "operator": "Or",
        "values": null
    }
}
```

2. `dynamicCriteria` property

Used with `Dynamic` filtering.

Possible values are: `Unknown`, `AboveAverage`, `AllDatesInPeriodApril`, `AllDatesInPeriodAugust`, `AllDatesInPeriodDecember`, `AllDatesInPeriodFebruray`, `AllDatesInPeriodJanuary`, `AllDatesInPeriodJuly`, `AllDatesInPeriodJune`, `AllDatesInPeriodMarch`, `AllDatesInPeriodMay`, `AllDatesInPeriodNovember`, `AllDatesInPeriodOctober`, `AllDatesInPeriodQuarter1`, `AllDatesInPeriodQuarter2`, `AllDatesInPeriodQuarter3`, `AllDatesInPeriodQuarter4`, `AllDatesInPeriodSeptember`, `BelowAverage`, `LastMonth`, `LastQuarter`, `LastWeek`, `LastYear`, `NextMonth`, `NextQuarter`, `NextWeek`, `NextYear`, `ThisMonth`, `ThisQuarter`, `ThisWeek`, `ThisYear`, `Today`, `Tomorrow`, `YearToDate`, `Yesterday`

Example how to filter values above the average. Set `filterOn` to `Dynamic` and `dynamicCriteria` to `AboveAverage`.

```
{
    "criteria": {
        "color": null,
        "criterion1": null,
        "criterion2": null,
        "filterOn": "Dynamic",
        "dynamicCriteria": "AboveAverage",
        "icon": null,
        "operator": "And",
        "values": null
    }
}
```

Documentation:

[Excel filterCriteria](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.filtercriteria?view=excel-js-preview)